# 404 issue with apache maven tomcat plugin for tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

i am using following configuration to rum tomcat 7 with maven

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

it was working fine
and suddenly now when trying to use `mvn tomcat7:run`

and trying to access:

http://localhost:8080/myapp

or any page in the application i just get 404 error

any ideas why i am facing such issue ?

Comment: no ideas ? is the issue that easy or that strange ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem.  My solution was only slightly related to the actual plugin.

I've upgraded to 2.0-beta-1.

The plugin was hiding the actual error from the console output.

I ran with the "old" tomcat plugin (mvn tomcat:run) and it showed my problem.

My applicationContext.xml wasn't getting loaded and that error was being swallowed.

Comment: where i can find the latest version of the plugin ?

Comment: I have this same issue. Unfortunately I can't run the old version of the tomcat plugin because it throws unrelated errors (due to my application only being runnable on tomcat7)

Comment: #droope Are you using project.build.finalName as the path like above?  What happens if you just use "/" for the context path?